# How should I model product images? Should they belong to the SKU or the Product?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, data-modeling, sku

I am building a custom e-commmerce website in Rails.

In my data model `products` have many `SKU`s, and `SKU`s have two properties: size and color.

I am wondering how I should add product images to this scheme.

One natural thing would be to put them on the product via a `has_many` relationship. But if I do this it might be difficult to account for the fact that SKUs with different colors on the same product have different images.

If, on the other hand, I add product images to SKUs in a `has_many` fashion then that will solve the color issue but raise a new one: within a color all SKUs have the same product images, regardless of their size.

I.e., product size doesn't affect a product's images but product color does.

Given that adding images to both products and SKUs has problems, perhaps I need to create a new model that captures the idea of `UserFacingProductEntity`.

However this problem must have been solved before.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to do this in a comment but it's not going to fit.

IMHO, it's how `sku` is defined. It's a common "issue", particularly if you're working to support an existing dataset (often years in the making, which means, can't change).

TLDR; each **variation** of a `Product` is a `sku`, it will be fulfilled/manufactured/distributed/tracked/reported on, that way *anyway*.

---

How "deep" variations go, color *and* size `skus` each? vs sizes are just "facets" of Color variation `skus`, will likely be dictated by *business' product line.*

Practical example: If I ordered ITEM A in RED, size L:

- how would I communicate that to both end user (display) and fulfillment operations (back office)?

  - pick/pack SKU 123 (red), and then find the "bin" with size L?
  - Is there even inventory? for 123L?
  - How do I manage ITEM A, RED, size L inventory, pricing, etc.  (vs sizes XL, M, S, etc)?

Or:

- is it "better" if sku 123 refers *specifically* to ITEM A, RED, Large? managed as it's own (mfg, inventory, pricing, etc)

At this point, the image (as above, only *one* aspect to consider) lives at the `color` variation `sku` level and/or `size` if it's is enough of a product type factor.

Hth...